# Is Savitzky-Golay filter a special case of an FIR lowpass filter?

Tags: lowpass-filter, estimation, finite-impulse-response

The Savitzky-Golay filter is explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savitzky%E2%80%93Golay_filter). It looks to me that any Savitzky-Golay filter can equally be considered an FIR filter. Am I right about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The Savitzky-Golay filter is a weighted sum of a finite number of data samples. So it is indeed an FIR filter (albeit, not causal, because it uses samples from the past and the future). And it is indeed a low-pass filter (smoother) as seen from the frequency response of the filter on the [same page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savitzky%E2%80%93Golay_filter).